# Spring ReST standards for returning

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am currently building a ReST service using spring.

The way I have it set up now is all of my endpoints are returning a ResponseEntity with associated status code and whatever POJO is associated with the request.

A GET request can look something like this

```
@RequestMapping( value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getFoo( @PathVariable(value="id") Long id )
{
    LOG.info("Getting Foo by ID: " + id);
    Foo foo = fooQuery.getFoo( id );

    if( foo != null )
        return new ResponseEntity<Foo>( foo, HttpStatus.OK );
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
}
```

Just wondering if this seems correct or if there is some other standard I should be following.

Comment: You can simplify this pretty extensively in most cases, such as by just returning the object itself or throwing an exception for Not Found.

Comment: Thanks chrylis, this is sort of what I am asking. I have seen it done both ways. Is there an advantage over returning the POJO vs returning a response entity?

Comment: Not having to manually fiddle with the entity, and being able to reuse logic if you share between JSON- and HTML-returning controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it simpler to throw exceptions, and use a `@ControllerAdvice` class to process all the exceptions. For example, here is a way I would write your code:

```
@GetMapping(value="{id}")
public Foo getFoo( @PathVariable(value="id") Long id )
{
    LOG.info("Getting Foo by ID: " + id);

    Foo foo = fooQuery.getFoo( id );
    MyUtil.validate(foo != null, "errorMessageCode");
   
    ... process foo
    return foo;
}
```

`MyUtil.validate` would check for the condition and throw an exception, say `MyException`. Then, I would have a `@ControllerAdvice` class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultExceptionHandler {

    @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object>
        handleMyException(MyException ex) {
        
        return MyUtil.mapOf("exception", "MyException",
                "message", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

If `fooQuery.getFoo` would return a *Java 8 Optional*, as in case of Spring Data Repositories, we can also use this construct to throw exceptions:

```
Foo foo = fooQuery.getFoo(id).orElseThrow(() ->
    new MyException("messageCode");
```

If it's helpful, [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) is a nice post on how to handle exceptions using @ControllerAdvice and orher alternatives.

(The above is actually a simpler version of a pattern that is used in [an open source project](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon).)

Comment: Thank you for this this is actually exactly the kind of pattern I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

REST isn't really a standard. There are conventions, and your implementation seems to fit within those conventions just fine. If you're building a REST service over a Spring Data repositories, I would recommend checking out [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) because it will create the controller for you and it uses [Hateoas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) to allow clients to more easily navigate your service.

[This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services) of the wiki page for REST has a pretty good example of methods and URI structure for a conventional REST service.

Comment: In the architecture we are currently using for the project Spring Data Rest will not be sufficient. I understand that this follows Restful conventions but am curious if there are some standards that people follow when implementing ReSTful services within the spring framework. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: As far as implementing Spring controllers, your implementation looks a lot like what I would implement